# MySQL update in join query executes very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got two tables which are `xp_pn_resale` and `xp_guru_properties`. I want to update the column `postal_code` from `xp_pn_resale` but the data comes from the `xp_guru_properties` and it is in a json object so I need to extract. I tried to write an query but it does not respond or not taking any output. Does anyone know whats the problem? Thanks

Here is my select query for reference and test

```
select r.block, r.street_name, 
r.postal_code, p.property_name,
r.property_name as resale_property_name,
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(p.json, '$.postcode') )as postcode
from xp_pn_resale AS r 
JOIN xp_guru_properties AS p 
ON r.property_name = p.property_name where r.postal_code is null 
limit 10
```

Result
[image]

I just want the `postcode` to be the value of `postal_code` from the query, I just set the limit to 10 because it takes too much time when i dont do limit

Also here is my update statement

```
UPDATE xp_pn_resale AS r
JOIN xp_guru_properties AS p ON r.property_name = p.property_name
SET r.postal_code = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(p.json, '$.postcode'))
where r.property_name = p.property_name
```

The query above does not do anything, it keeps executing. I dont know whats wrong with the query i wrote

I got 800k data in `xp_pn_resale` and 30k in `xp_guru_properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query does not need the `WHERE` clause, so:

```
UPDATE xp_pn_resale r JOIN
       xp_guru_properties p
       ON r.property_name = p.property_name
    SET r.postal_code = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(p.json, '$.postcode'));
```

I might suspect one of two things.  The first is an index on `xp_guru_properties(property_name)`.  That is important for performance.

The second is that there are multiple matches in the properties table for a single property.  That will really slow things down.

Comment: why my query doesnt need a `where` clause sir?

Comment: @Vince . . . You might need a `where` clause if you really want the condition on `r.postal_code is null `.  However, your `where` clause is the same as the `on` clause.

Comment: okay I see, but the query seems slow to run. I tried executing it and until now its not done. almost and hour or two. what seems to be the problem sir?

Comment: @Vince . . . do you have the recommended index?

Comment: what do you mean recommended index? I only matched `property_name` from `xp_pn_resale` and `property_name` from `xp_guru_properties`

Comment: The query is right, i just need to add index in order to optimize it

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
UPDATE xp_pn_resale
INNER JOIN xp_guru_properties
ON xp_pn_resale.property_name = xp_guru_properties.property_name
SET xp_pn_resale.postal_code = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(xp_guru_properties.json, '$.postcode'))
WHERE xp_pn_resale.postal_code is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I already executed your query, Im waiting for the result. It took so long to execute since it has too much data

Comment: Its a bit similar to my query above